# TTK button size with different Windows scalings

Tags: python, ttk, ttkthemes

I have written a Python application with the sv_ttk Deisgn.
A button looks like this, for example:

```
execute_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Execute", command=lambda:  execute_command(command_entry.get()), style='Modern.TButton')
execute_button.pack(pady=10)
execute_button.bind("<Enter>", lambda _: execute_button.config(cursor="hand2"))
execute_button.bind("<Leave>", lambda _: execute_button.config(cursor=""))
execute_button.config(width=15, style='Modern.TButton')
```

But when I open it on another Windows device with a different default screen zoom, the buttons are much too small.

How can I solve this?
Many thanks for your help in advance,
schBenedikt

I've already done several deep internet searches, also tried to implement a manual zoom in the code

Comment: Try setting the Dpi awareness for the process.
`from ctypes import windll`
`windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)`

Comment: No - that doesn't help.